# Circular Shift with GMP

Tags: c, gmp

I am trying to implement SHA - 1 algorithm using gmp library. I haven't found any indication of existence of such function. Can someone give an example of how it could be done?

Comment: http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/nettle/

Comment: There are [(8.1) Low-level functions for cryptography here](https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html#Low_002dlevel-Functions) or you can use the low level bitwise functions to do what you need